# Ubuntu install boots into BusyBox

Tags: ubuntu, boot, busybox

I'm trying to install Ubuntu on a wiped drive and for some reason when i choose the install option, it goes to the BusyBox built in shell. Can anyone tell me why it would do that and how to get to the regular install?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Ubuntu version 9.04

Answer (score 2):

> this is probably because i'm not using
>   sata drives, i'm using IDE drives

I faced this problem quite some time ago ( on a normal system) - Used this workaround

> At the LiveCD initial boot screen:
>
> - Select <kbd>F6</kbd> for more options
> - Add the following option to the beginning of the options list: `break=top`
> - Press enter to start booting. Ubuntu will start booting, but kick you out to a command prompt
> - At the prompt type these two commands: `modprobe piix` & `exit`
> - You will now boot into the LiveCD normally

Thanks to [UbuntuForums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=421588), I had this delicious'd

Comment: I tried this and it says all the mountings failed and "No init found".

Comment: This worked for Ubuntu 12.04 on old hardware!

Answer (score 1):

This is almost always due to a fatal error during the boot process. Does this happen once you boot of a fresh install, or does it happen when booting from the live cd?

At first, the internet actually does not seem to be that helpful for this error. I kept getting the same problem a while back, and I never figured how to fix it. But alas, do not give up!

Assuming the live CD works, try booting from it and mount the 'broken' install as the root (where `hda1` is the 'name' of the hard drive):

```
mkdir ~/Desktop/harddrive
sudo mount -rw /dev/hda1 ~/Desktop/harddrive
sudo chroot ~/Desktop/harddrive
sudo aptitude reinstall ubuntu-minimal
```

Hopefull, this will reinstall the base ubuntu system.

---

I also found [this gem](http://www.ubuntu.com/getubuntu/releasenotes/904#Boot%20failures%20on%20systems%20with%20Intel%20D945%20motherboards) from the Ubuntu 9.04 [release notes](http://www.ubuntu.com/getubuntu/releasenotes/904):

> ### Boot failures on systems with Intel D945 motherboards
>
> Users have reported slower than normal detection of SATA hard drives on systems with Intel D945 motherboards in Ubuntu 9.04. This may cause the system to drop to a busybox initramfs shell on boot with a "Gave up waiting for root device." error. Wait a minute or two and then exit the initramfs shell by typing `exit`. Booting should proceed normally. If it doesn't, wait a bit longer and try again. Once the system boots, edit `/boot/grub/menu.lst` and add `rootdelay=90` to the kernel stanza for your current kernel. ([Bug 290153](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/290153))

Comment: unfortunately the live cd does the same thing. brings me to the same place :(

Comment: thanks for the update. unfortunately this does not work either. it errors when i type exit. this is probably because i'm not using sata drives, i'm using IDE drives.

Comment: Have you ever had Ubuntu working on your computer? It may just be a simple case of incompatible hardware, so you just might not be able to use Ubuntu...

Comment: No this is a computer i just put together from a bunch of parts i had laying around. I guess i'll look into another distro.