# Ubuntu 9.10 install won't boot after filesystem damage

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, boot

I was running a somewhat standard install of Ubuntu 9.10, when my drive got pushed into read-only mode, so I switched to `tty1`, ran `/etc/init.d/gdm stop`, and then ran `fsck -y /`. It took an hour or too, but eventually finished. However, now that partition is unbootable, and upon attempting to boot into Ubuntu, it complains about `libsepol.so.1` as missing and starts a recovery shell. In this recovery shell, only certain tools work. `ls` complains about `libacl.so.1`, and the filesystem is still read-only. When I try `mount -rw /dev/sda1`, it complains about `libsepol.so.1` again. I can however still run fsck. I tried running it with `fsck -p -f /`, and it completes, much quicker, but the system remains unbootable. I could probably boot into the Ubuntu live-cd to get read-write access, but I wouldn't know what to do. Any suggestions?

I read an interesting suggestion [here](https://superuser.com/questions/52623/ubuntu-install-boots-into-busybox/52625#52625), but I don't know how I would go about reinstalling the base Ubuntu packages without write access to the hd, or through the live cd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Start Linux from a live-cd
Mount your hard disk (e.g. on /mnt)
Restore libsepol.so.1 (and anything else that might have been corrupted) to your hard disk from the live cd

Comment: I'm accepting this, but I just decided to reinstall, backing up all that I can.